# Join text with layer

Tags: qgis

In Mapinfo it´s easy to link a text-layer with a geometric layer by attributes with outcome as a new layer. Where and how to do this in Q-GIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Called a Join in QGIS, done from the Joins tab from a layers properties, a bit dated guide but functional:

http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/join_csv.php

Comment: Thx. Already tried that  one, but couldn't generate any output. Must be the structure behind the fields that I'll have to correct.